# Representing destinations in a square

Tags: c++, inheritance, vectors, constructor

I've written a program following the instructions of an exam paper. There are no solutions available so I would appreciate a feedback. I'm concerned with `main` in particular (I've already posted a similar question [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/192917/a-simple-program-with-trains-and-inheritance)). I've tried to solve the problem as I've seen it's done in other solutions made available by our teacher. Also the constructors made me think a lot.

I was asked to make a program to represent destinations in a square [0,1]x[0,1], a salesman that has to go in some destinations in that square and another salesman inheriting from the former but with slightly different habits.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>

class Location {
private:
    double x_, y_;
public:
    Location(double x, double y) : x_(x), y_(y) { }
    Location() {
        x_ = drand48();
        y_ = drand48();
    }
    Location(const Location & L) : x_(L.x_), y_(L.y_) { }
    double getx() {return x_; }
    bool operator<(const Location & L) { return x_ < L.x_; }

    double distance(const Location & L) {
        return std::sqrt(std::pow(x_ - L.x_, 2) + std::pow(y_ - L.y_, 2));
    }

};

class Salesman {
private:
    Location start_;
protected:
    std::vector<Location> tobevisited_;
public:
    Salesman(const Location & start, std::vector<Location>::iterator it1, std::vector<Location>::iterator it2) : start_(start), tobevisited_(it1, it2) { }

    int ndest() { return tobevisited_.size(); }

    virtual double visit() {
        double dist = 0;
        sort(tobevisited_.begin(), tobevisited_.end());
        dist = (*(tobevisited_.begin())).distance(start_);
        for(std::vector<Location>::iterator it = tobevisited_.begin()+1; it != tobevisited_.end(); it++) {
            dist += (*(it)).distance(*(it-1));
        }
        return dist;
    }


};

class LazySalesman : public Salesman {
private:
    double d_;
public:
    LazySalesman(double d, std::vector<Location>::iterator it1, std::vector<Location>::iterator it2) : d_(d), Salesman(Location(0,0), it1, it2) { }

    double visit() {
        double dist = 0;
        dist = Salesman::visit();
        dist += d_*ndest();
    }
};

int main() {

    srand48(time(NULL));
    Location start(0., 0.);
    Location start2(1,1);
    int cont = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<3000; i++) {
        std::vector<Location> v;

        for(int j=0; j<10; j++) {
            v.push_back(Location());
        }
        Salesman Willy(start, v.begin(), v.end());
        if(Willy.visit() < 2.) cont++;
    }

    std::cout << "cont = " << cont << std::endl;

    std::vector<Location> loc;
    Location a(0.1, 0.1);
    Location b(0.5, 0.1);
    Location c(0.5, 0.5);
    loc.push_back(a);
    loc.push_back(b);
    loc.push_back(c);

    std::vector<Salesman*> vett;

    vett.push_back(new Salesman(start2, loc.begin(), loc.end()));
    vett.push_back(new LazySalesman(0.1, loc.begin(), loc.end()));
    vett.push_back(new LazySalesman(0.5, loc.begin(), loc.end()));

    for(auto el : vett) {
        std::cout << el->visit() << std::endl;
        delete el;
    }           

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tell your instructor to become familiar with the **Standard Guidelines**.  You can find presentations on youtube where Stroustrup introduces this as a keynote speech, and many others speaking on them since.

---

Don’t use naked `new` (and `delete`).  Make your vector of `unique_ptr` instead.

The srand48 is not a standard function.  And the old C rand/srand are infamous for poor quality random numbers.  See the [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) header file.

Why does one location use `0.` (funny way to write `0.0`, a `double`) and the other use `1` as an `int`?

You don’t need to put `private:` at the top of the class; that is assumed.

Does `visit` modify the object? You did not make it `const`.  Also, use the `override` keyword in the derived version!  That is very important in real code for maintainability as well as error checking.

```
for(int j=0; j<10; j++)  v.push_back(Location());
```

Did you know that vector elements are always initialized? And what will it use do you suppose?  The default constructor of the element, of course!

So just write:  `v.resize(10+v.size())`  to add 10 default locations to the end.

```
Location a(0.1, 0.1);
```

Use *uniform initialization* syntax.

```
Location a{0.1, 0.1};
```

Thou hast scribed an olde dialect.  You’re using the ranged `for` loop so your textbook must be written after 2011; perhaps it is just a slightly updated lesson plan from 1998?

---

```
Location() {
    x_ = drand48();
    y_ = drand48();
}
```

A random-initialized location might be handy for this specific program, but it’s sufficiently bizzare that it hinders the understanding of the code.  Make a function to return a random location instead!

---

```
double getx() {return x_; }
bool operator<(const Location & L) { return x_ < L.x_; }
```

You are definitly missing `const` on your member functions.

Writing good relational operators is a whole lesson and not the point here — this is probably fine for the class as it stands, but reviewers will wonder why you didn’t make it a non-member and supply all the relational and equality operators.

Since the (partial) ordering exists specifically for your algorithm, you might want to make it a named function instead. Consider the future maintainer that writes a test using `>` and then has to figure out why it didn’t compile, and of course documenting that less means East and is not a complete ordering.

---

```
double distance(const Location & L) {
    return std::sqrt(std::pow(x_ - L.x_, 2) + std::pow(y_ - L.y_, 2));
```

Besides being `const`, just call [`std::hypot`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/hypot).  It will be faster and more accurate.

---

```
Salesman(const Location & start, std::vector<Location>::iterator it1, std::vector<Location>::iterator it2) 
: start_(start), tobevisited_(it1, it2) 
{ }
```

Very interesting that you allow salesman to be initialized with a segment of a larger vector.  Is that a use case you anticipate (e.g. a huge list divided up among several salesmen)?

It’s enlightened but only part way to what we expect: it is limited to segments of another vector, and can’t take begin/end iterators to locations *in general* (anything that can be iterated).

Also, you should be using the `const_iterator`.

Here is the simple/direct way to take that information in the constructor.

```
      ⋮
    Location start_;
    std::vector<Location> tobevisited_;
public:
    Salesman (start, std::vector<Location> locations) 
      : start_{start}, tobevisited_{std::move(locations)} 
      { }
```

---

Get a post-it note and write using a fat marker, “**Can it be `const`?**”. Stick that on the edge of your monitor.

Comment: thank you for your insights, I hadn't thought about the uselessness of the nested for! I'll try to renew my dialect. I gave to the constructor of salesman iterators of a vector because it seemed to me the easiest way to define his protected member

Comment: Just pass the vector as a single parameter.  (In fact, this will be a “sink” parameter so pass by value and `move` in the initialization list.)  `Salesman Willy{start, v};`